# Spacer not pushing view to top of screen inside ZStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I position my search-bar and button to the top of the screen with 65 padding from the top AND KEEP the onTapGestureFunctionality?

I tried the modifiers .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) with padding(.top, 65) applied to the VStack inside my ZStack but then my onTapGesture would not work when tapping on either the search bar or the button...

Why does the Spacer() only push the elements about 80% to the top of the screen? Could this be because its inside a navigation view?

See image below.

Thank you

[image]

```
struct MapScreen: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                VStack {
                    HStack(spacing: 15) {
                        SearchBar()
                            .padding(.leading, 5)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print("search pressed")
                      
                            }
                        ActivateClaimButton()
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print("claim pressed")
                            }
                    }
                    // 2 modifiers below positions correctly but
                    // onTapGesture doesn't work
                    // .padding(.top, 65)
                    // .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

                    Spacer() 
                }.zIndex(2)
               
                MapView(locations: $locations, spotArray: $spotArray).edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
                BottomNavBar().zIndex(1).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all).offset(y: 35)
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presentSearchView, content: {
                SearchView()
             })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ZStack works on the Z axis ie: overlay. Spacer will push front or back in the on screen perspective. Move your spacer into  the VStack which works on the y axis ie: up and down in relation to viewing the screen.

Comment: The space may be the `NavigationView` try hiding it `.navigationBarHidden(true)`

Comment: BTW hardcoded values like `offset(y: 35)` or `padding(.top, 65)` usually only work on one screen size. The `View` will not size well with other devices.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that worked for me was

```
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```